# Change not add value to variable

Tags: jquery

I want to assign new value to current price when checkbox is checked.
My code for that is :

```
var price = 10;
var item = $(".item");
var total = $(".total");

$(".item").change(function() {
    price += item.val(); // not working
    // price += 10;  // not working
    // alert('debug'); //work
});

// if i add outside change block work perfect
// price += 10 // work

total.text(price);

<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="item">
<div class="total"></div>
```

Whay value of `price` was not changed inside `change` block? What i do wrong?

Comment: It's working for me, but you probably want to convert `item.val()` from a string to an number first. https://jsfiddle.net/eoefrsma/

Comment: Before this code i just do that `parseInt` but in comment i assign int to price `price += 10` whay to convert int to int

Comment: How do you know the variable doesn't change? You never display the new value after changing it.

Comment: I debug it with `alert`

Comment: With `alert('debug')`? How does printing "debug" help?

Comment: omg man am not idiot. This not work, if is checked alert with 'debug' message is triggered so block is TRUE...  if i do that outside block and try to assign to price new value `+= 10` working.

Comment: Again, *how do you know the value doesn't change*? Do you expect `total.text(price)` to keep track of `price` and change the display value automatically? (It doesn't.) What does it show if you do `alert(price)` instead?

Comment: I know is not change bcs text is not updated. When i do alert(price) value is 10. Its not changed

Comment: Well, good luck figuring it out; the code you have in the question does change the value (although without parseInt it appends it as string.) https://jsfiddle.net/m39179f0/ Unless you show your real code there's nothing anyone can do to help.

Comment: @Juhana looking ur fiddle example its work but whay `total.text(price);` does not have new value `10+1 = 11` in my case i want just to update that output to new value

Comment: Like I've said multiple times: You need to update the output every time you change the value. If you do `total.text(price)` just once it does **not** keep track of the variable and update the output automatically.

Comment: Sorry i dont know realy good english. Ur right i put in block and now work. thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues that are going on.

1. Your jQuery is not in a document ready function, so is not binding because the element doesn't exist yet.
2. Your setting the total value *outside* of your function, so it's not updating.
3. The value should be cast to a number, so that you get a proper "addition".  This is done by adding a `+` immediately before the variable.
4. You're always adding the price, even when you uncheck.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/oa489w5d/1/)

The javascript should look like this:

```
// Document ready - wait until all elements are loaded before binding
jQuery(function($) {
  var price = 10;
  // Assign this INSIDE the document ready
  var total = $(".total");
  // Bind events INSIDE document ready
  $(".item").change(function() {
    // When this was outside, you could only have ONE "item"
    var item = $(this);
    // Only add if checked
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
      // the +item.val() "casts" the value as a number
      price += +item.val();
    } else {
      price -= +item.val();
    }
    // Update the total value
    total.text(price);
  });
  // Put the total value in on initial load
  total.text(price);
});
```